# Assign JSON data to a variable in python

Tags: python, json

I am working with an API and I need to assign data from the response to a variable. I am doing it the way I thought it would work but I am getting an error. I am trying to assign the lat to the variable `locationLat` by doing the following:

```
locationLat = json_data["results"]["locations"]["latLng"]["lat"]
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
{
"info": {
    "statuscode": 0,
    "copyright": {
        "text": "© 2021 MapQuest, Inc.",
        "imageUrl": "http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif",
        "imageAltText": "© 2021 MapQuest, Inc."
    },
    "messages": []
},
"options": {
    "maxResults": -1,
    "thumbMaps": true,
    "ignoreLatLngInput": false
},
"results": [
    {
        "providedLocation": {
            "location": "Clarendon"
        },
        "locations": [
            {
                "street": "",
                "adminArea6": "",
                "adminArea6Type": "Neighborhood",
                "adminArea5": "Clarendon",
                "adminArea5Type": "City",
                "adminArea4": "Donley County",
                "adminArea4Type": "County",
                "adminArea3": "TX",
                "adminArea3Type": "State",
                "adminArea1": "US",
                "adminArea1Type": "Country",
                "postalCode": "",
                "geocodeQualityCode": "A5XAX",
                "geocodeQuality": "CITY",
                "dragPoint": false,
                "sideOfStreet": "N",
                "linkId": "282031575",
                "unknownInput": "",
                "type": "s",
                "latLng": {
                    "lat": 34.939307,
                    "lng": -100.890953
```

Comment: `json_data["results"]` is a list.

Answer (score 1):

The data under `"results"` is a list, not a dictionary. You would need to select an element in a list to access before trying to access its `"locations"`. The data under `"locations"` is also a list, so you would need to consider that too. For instance, if you needed the first item in `"results"` and in `"locations"`, the right way to access it would be

```py
json_data["results"][0]["locations"][0]["latLng"]["lat"]
```

Comment: Of course, I see now. I didn't look out for the difference between the square and curly brackets. It worked, thank you so much!